# How python to read multiple JSON files and return as multipledict

Tags: python, json

Current file in the path:
My current script is depends on the needs to generate n of data_out file.

```
data_out_1.json
data_out_2.json
data_out_3.json
...
data_out_i.json
```

Here is my code to write the JSON file to local directory:

```
out_file = open("myfile.json", "w")
json.dump(result_disk, out_file, indent=2)
out_file.close()
print(out_file)

with open('myfile.json', 'r') as f_in:
    data = json.load(f_in)

for i, point in enumerate(data['Value'], 1):

with open('data_out_{}.json'.format(i), 'w') as f_out:
d = point
#d['Value'] = point
json.dump(d, f_out, indent=4)
```

myfile.json:

```
{
  "Value": [
    {
      "Computer": "mary",
      "ObjectName": "Logical Disk",
      "point": "point1",
    },
    {
      "Computer": "kitty",
      "ObjectName": "Logical Disk",
      "point": "point2",
    },
    {
      "Computer": "peter",
      "ObjectName": "Logical Disk",
      "point": "point3",
    }
  ]
}
```

data_out_1.json

```
{
  "Computer": "mary",
  "ObjectName": "Logical Disk",
  "point": "point1",
}
```

data_out_2.json

```
{
  "Computer": "kitty",
  "ObjectName": "Logical Disk",
  "point": "point2",
}
```

data_out_3.json

```
{
  "Computer": "peter",
  "ObjectName": "Logical Disk",
  "point": "point3",
}
```

What I want is to read those data_out_n.json file into dict, and get:

```
dict1=json.dumps(data_out_1)
dict2=json.dumps(data_out_2)
dict3=json.dumps(data_out_3)
```

I am currently trying to get read all json files by the path method, and read by all_files[0]...

```
path = os.getcwd()
print(path)
folderpath = path
filepaths = [os.path.join(folderpath, name) for name in os.listdir(folderpath)]
all_files = []

for path1 in filepaths:
with open(path1, 'r') as f:
file = f.readlines()
all_files.append(file)
```

Any better way to get the expected result?

Comment: `json.dumps` returns a string; assigning that to variables called `dict1` etc seems to not be what you want.

Comment: You should also fix your current code: the indentation is missing.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the `pathlib` module!

```py
from pathlib import Path
import json

path = Path.cwd() / Path('data')
files = [file for file in path.iterdir()]
# files = 
# [PosixPath('/home/devuser/application/data/data1.json'),
#  PosixPath('/home/devuser/application/data/data2.json'),
#  PosixPath('/home/devuser/application/data/data3.json')]

dicts = []
for file in files:
    with open(str(file), 'r') as f:
        dicts.append(json.loads(''.join(f.readlines())))
# dicts = 
# [{'Computer': 'mary', 'ObjectName': 'Logical Disk', 'point': 'point1'},
#  {'Computer': 'kitty', 'ObjectName': 'Logical Disk', 'point': 'point2'},
#  {'Computer': 'peter', 'ObjectName': 'Logical Disk', 'point': 'point3'}]
```